# Way to get all table and column names from the T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have very large query (here are used more than 100 tables and thousands of columns), and I need to get list of all columns and tables used in this query. Maybe there is any already created software or script to achieve that?

For example:

Query:

```
SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t2.Col4, t2.Coln
FROM TableName1 t1
JOIN TableName2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col4
```

Output should be:

```
TableName1
Col1
Col2
Col3

TableName2
Col4
Coln
```

Comment: `Describe` somehow? Environment?

Comment: Why do you need to select from hundreds of tables and thousands of columns? Does anyone need them at all? Where do you need to output them?

Comment: Think about how complex a query can become. There is really no way to programmatically look at a query and determine what tables are involved. Now consider the next level, what about functions in your query? do you need to know those tables also? The only way to do this is to sit down with the code and parse it manually.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you need that output?

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is needed for Replication (I need to provide for some guys all table and column names whose are used in stored procedures that they could replicate It)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments asking why you need such information and why a query would need to query so many tables.  That aside, this is still solvable.

Some low-tech ways would be:

1. If all tables referenced in the query are schema-qualified (like `dbo.table_name`), which they should be for best performance, search for your schema in a text editor, or write a small shell script to parse the query text for `dbo`.
2. Extract the execution plan of the query and extract a list of objects from it using XML.

But this is what I would do.  This is probably the simplest and most reliable.  *Put the query into a stored procedure, install the procedure, and check its dependencies.*

In SQL Server Management Studio, if you right-click a stored procedure, there is a 'View Dependencies' menu item which will show you which tables it relies on.  If you need a more programmatic answer, you can extract the dependencies from DMV's (sys.dm_*).

```
select re.referenced_schema_name + '.' + re.referenced_entity_name as table_name
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('PROC_NAME', 'OBJECT') re
where re.referenced_minor_id = 0;
```

This also returns a row for any functions the query calls.  If needed, I'm sure you can filter those out by joining to a DMV that breaks down object types.